# Calculate Length in Perspective View

Tags: math, perspective

I have a 4-sided plane in a perspective view. Each side is equal in length to the side across from it. Given the length of two sides and the fore-shortened length of one side, how can we solve for the other two sides?

*Assume the bottom side is not fore-shortened in this example.*

[image: perspective view]

*Edited with additional information.*

[image]

Comment: Have you tried http://math.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Unfortunately, math.stackexchange.com won't allow new users to post images. I'll still put the question up there as well. Seeing as I need to produce code to calculate this, maybe stackoverflow users can help.

Comment: @Abdulla: This is simple geometry, no? It will be if you have all the info. You are missing a length or angle.

Comment: The idea is to calculate the distance between the two horizontal sides based on the fore-shortening of the top side.

Comment: Closed as cross-site post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135679/calculate-length-in-perspective-view